# How Ubuntu plans to support PHP7?

Tags: 14.04, server, php, repository, support

Tomorrow will be release PHP 7, how Ubuntu plans to support it? It will be available at least in official LTS repository or we need to wait the next Ubuntu release?

Comment: The folks at Zend might release their own repositories the same way they've done with the beta version (of course this is just a guess).  But even if they don't, someone else probably will.

Comment: @SledgeHammer yes I know, I'm curious about Ubuntu repository...

Comment: I reported a ["bug" on launchpad to include php7](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1522422). I hope to see soon a php7 package in supporting Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install PHP 7?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7)

Answer (score 5):

The new upstream PHP 7.0 won't be supported in existing releases.  The policy on bringing new stuff to existing releases is very clear on that -> only security releases go in.  You can read about the Ubuntu policy here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates

The good news is that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will be released with PHP 7.0 packages.  Nish from Canonical made an heroic effort to push my Debian packaging into Ubuntu 16.04 and he has also updated many packages that depend on PHP and cleaned up the rest that doesn't support PHP 7.0 (yet or never will).

If you want to use PHP 7.0 on older Ubuntu releases, the only way is to use some external means, like my `ppa:ondrej/php` PPA that carry co-installable PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0 for Ubuntu 14.04 and later.

Comment: Thank you, but I would never use a PPA in a production system.

Comment: Then you are out of luck for existing Ubuntu releases, because https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates

Comment: I trust in your PPA, maybe this time I'll make an exception. Do you think that will be included in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I spoke to Ubuntu PHP maintainer and PHP 7.0 might make it to Ubuntu 16.04. But no promises, that's yet to be decided.

Comment: Xenial alpha 1 is out, and I don't see PHP7 on this page: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php/

Comment: @Andrew It's there: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php/php7.0

Comment: @DigNative They must have just added it. It wasn't there when I posted my comment last Wednesday.

Answer (score -1):

PHP 7.0 is currently available in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS BETA. I run it myself and it works.

Additionally, PHP 7 appears as package "php" and php5 as "php5".

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/539930)

Comment: @Pilot6 What are you talking about? I answered about Ubuntu's plan's to support it. They are supporting it in the next LTS.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Comment: @muru The screenshot is for proof in case anyone asks where I got this from. The text is not relevant and should not be indexed. It is also not copiable, being from a virtual machine session.

Comment: You don't need [a screenshot](http://superuser.com/q/1010186/334516) for that. Install SSH on your VM, SSH to it from your local system, and copy away to your heart's desire.

Comment: Why should I bother about an answer that's no better than [a comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/704986/how-ubuntu-plans-to-support-php7/747351?noredirect=1#comment1063712_705413)? And no, the PHP 7 packages are named `php7.0` etc. `php` depends on `php7.0` as the first option.

Comment: @muru The posted answer with 4 upvotes is outdated and incorrect, yet mine is down-voted. Why don't you format something useful yourself.

Comment: Take care, whoever finally votes to delete this post, to write a suitable answer so that there is at least one.

Comment: FYI: the other answer is still true: Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 don't and won't get PHP 7.

Comment: I see, yes, the question was about 14.04. The OP did not even consider that Ubuntu was debating whether or not to include it in 16.04. This is a main result on Google search for the subject though, and none of the Google results tell about 16.04 having PHP 7, only guesswork. I don't know how I found it myself. I think I just ran the upgrade to the beta.

Comment: That's because questions about specific details in a future Ubuntu release are mostly off-topic and posting your half-baked answer here under the 14.04 tag just because your Google search results look inaccurate *to you* (mine have a result that links to packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php7.0) doesn't rectify the situation it makes it worse. You only write that something exists and respond with a passive-aggressive attitude to constructive feedback. Don't expect that someone else writes the missing good parts of your answer for your benefit. Look at my top voted answer to see how it could be done.