# Unable to locate package php7.0

Tags: apt

I have "Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS" OS and trying to install PHP7 using command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-7.0
```

Getting error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php-7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php-7.0'

sudo apt-get install php7.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
```

How it can be fix Please advise.

Comment: Your command doesn't match the output, since it has `php-7.0` and the output has `php7.0`. Aside from that, there is no package with a name like that in the standard repositories. Are you trying to use a PPA? If so, perhaps https://askubuntu.com/a/705893/147763 can help.

Comment: @Olathe: I have also tried commands: **sudo apt-get install php-7.0** and  **sudo apt-get install php7.0**

Comment: How to install php 7, see:http://askubuntu.com/q/705880/476968

Answer (score 87, accepted):

PHP 7 is not available for Ubuntu Trusty in the standard Ubuntu repositories (2016-01-02).

You could use the PPA `ppa:ondrej/php`

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Comment: Thanks ! See the output of $php -v Below:

PHP 7.0.1-4+deb.sury.org~vivid+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
 with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

Comment: PHP6 doesn't exist, see [the PHP website](http://php.net/)

Comment: Not only does PHP 6 not exist, the naming scheme will change to php5.5, php5.6, etc. in coming versions.

Comment: Need `phpmyadmin`, there is no `php7.0-phpmyadmin`, `php5.6-phpmyadmin` or `php5.5-phpmyadmin`, nor `phpmyadmin` compatible with your php.

Comment: Hello, I want to add php7.2 on my server in ubuntu 15.10. Is it possible?

Comment: I perfromed above mention command and still i am getting error of unable to locate package of php7.3. I updated apt-get update also

Comment: Does not work anymore on ubuntu 14. Not sure why but come up with errors `E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'`.

Comment: getting this 
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2'`

Comment: @GeorgeMylonas - this is because the developer (ondrej) who puts together the php7 repo does not support EOL (end of life) releases (i.e. Ubuntu 14).