# How do I remove PHP 7 Completely?

Tags: 14.04, php

I have upgraded PHP old version to latest php7 but unable to start its services.

```
systemctl restart apache2.service

Job for apache2.service failed. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Status Detail:

```
systemctl status apache2.service


● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-01-04 13:58:17 IST; 5s ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Process: 16666 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited,       status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 04 13:58:17 GCT022 apache2[16666]: *
Jan 04 13:58:17 GCT022 apache2[16666]: * The apache2 configtest failed.
Jan 04 13:58:17 GCT022 apache2[16666]: Output of config test was:
Jan 04 13:58:17 GCT022 apache2[16666]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2...
Jan 04 13:58:17 GCT022 apache2[16666]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Jan 04 13:58:17 GCT022 apache2[16666]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jan 04 13:58:17 GCT022 systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exit...s=1
Jan 04 13:58:17 GCT022 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Jan 04 13:58:17 GCT022 systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
Jan 04 13:58:17 GCT022 systemd[1]: apache2.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
root@client022:/home/user22$ ^C
```

Now I want to revert back or remove php7 that i can do the user machine active with the old version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I have answered your question [Unable to locate package php7.0](https://askubuntu.com/q/715944/367165) and you have accepted my answer and because you explicitly ask for a removal of the package:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
```

Comment: It was installed all the packages and I have checked day its PHP-v it was Ok Shutdown the System today, just checked that php7 unable start services so maybe it is the different issue.

Comment: $ _sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php-7.0_  **sudo: ppa-purge: command not found**

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 111):

To remove php7.0 use

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.0-common
```

Answer (score 37):

This will remove all php7 version, be it php 7.0 or php 7.1 etc..

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be sudo apt-get purge php7.* ?

Comment: This also purged my php5.

Comment: @kurdtpage +1 
I tried it again and yes it did purged php5. also, don't know why though that was not the case earlier .

Comment: @AbhishekPareek the `*` is a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) star, not a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) star.

Answer (score 5):

If you run Abhishek's it will remove other packages. On mine it was going to remove these too

> The following packages will be REMOVED
>
> libapache2-mod-php5.5*
> libapache2-mod-php5.6* php-common* php-gettext*   php-igbinary*
> php-memcached* php-msgpack* php-pear* php-xdebug* php5-cli*
> php5-common* php5-dev* php5-json* php5-memcache* php5-memcached*
> php5-readline* php5-redis* php5-xdebug* php5.5-cli* php5.5-common*
> php5.5-curl* php5.5-json* php5.5-mysql* php5.5-opcache*
> php5.5-readline*   php5.5-xml* php5.6* php5.6-cli* php5.6-common*
> php5.6-curl* php5.6-fpm*   php5.6-json* php5.6-mbstring* php5.6-mysql*
> php5.6-opcache* php5.6-readline*   php5.6-xml* pkg-php-tools*

So you're better off with

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
```

Answer (score 5):

to remove php7.x simpely use

```
sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php7.2| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "`
```

Answer (score 3):

The way to remove PHP and dependencies is:

```
apt-get autoremove php7.0
```

Comment: This is the same as most of the other answers.

Comment: I don't think any of the other answers suggest precisely this...

Comment: @Zanna You are right. Moreover, this seems to work on my Ubuntu 16.04 but giving a package name to `apt-get autoremove` is not documented in the man page.

Comment: @Melebius yes it works for me on 17.10 too - `autoremove` in place of `remove` causes the orphaned dependencies to be removed at the same time, which saves running an additional command. I don't know why it is not documented as it's very useful!

Answer (score 2):

After doing a:

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
```

to remove **all versions of php7**, you still need to run some extra steps to *completely and utterly remove php7*:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Then do a:

```
whereis php
```

and then remove all directories in the output of the last command, E.G.:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/php
```