# Removing php7: whereis gives etc/php, not sure about nginx files

Tags: nginx, php7

Sorry I have two questions. I want to remove php7.4 to install php8.0. I followed the link:
[How do I remove PHP 7 Completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716661/how-do-i-remove-php-7-completely)

used the commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
sudo apt-get purge `dpkg -l | grep php7.2| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "``
```

(1)Still somebody  please guide me why I am getting:

```
$ whereis php
php: /etc/php
```

(2)Do I have to reinstall nginx?
Zulfi.