# phpmyadmin not working due to missing extensions

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am about to use `phpmyadmin` on Ubuntu 16.04. But it shows that the page is not working. the error log says `error 500`

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 477
```

At first it says that the `mysqli|mysql` extension is missing. but after sleepless hours I forget what I've been done to it. I am using php7.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
```

or simply:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gettext
```

and then:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This has been reported at this bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1577482

Comment: I am setting up a server for the first time and I had the same issue as the op, except that I wasn't upgrading it was a fresh install of 16.04.  The same issue however, and this fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks you, I had the same problem, it worked, +1 from me.

Comment: `sudo apt install php-gettext` is enough. This installs the others.

Comment: This doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04. Any other ideas?

Comment: Found it! You have to Manually add the Repository. https://askubuntu.com/a/715947/619039

Answer (score 6):

You need to install php-gettext , Install it using

```
 sudo apt-get install php-gettext
```

Answer (score 6):

I lost hours to solve this problem. Just install `php-mbstring`, `php7.0-mbstring` and `php-gettext`. That's it.

You can do that by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
```

Comment: I haven't installed/tried 16.04 yet, but I would assume installing `php-mbstring` would automatically install `php7-mbstring` if you have php7 installed.

Comment: Maybe you are right; maybe that's just a metapacket.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, my problem was with the folder creation. When I was installing the php-gettext lib with:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gettext
```

Two folders are created in `usr/share/php`

Folder 1 - `usr/share/php/php-gettext`
Folder 2 - `usr/share/php/php-phpgettext`

And inside the first folder some symbolic links to the second folder.

I deleted the first folder with:

```
sudo rm -r usr/share/php/php-gettext
```

And then copy the php-php-gettext folder to php-gettext with:

```
sudo cp -r php-php-gettext php-gettext
```

Now my `phpmyadmin` works.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Synaptic Package Manager, install `php7.0-mbstring`, and do `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 0):

I Try this:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`
and set socket on **TCP/IP**. After the
`sudo apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext`
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

If you installed phpymadmin from the archives, php-gettext is a dependency and would be automatically installed.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext

sudo service apache2 restart
```

http://www.dailytechnoblog.com/how-to-resolve-phpmyadmin-error-the-mbstring-extension-is-missing-please-check-your-php-configuration/