# phpmyadmin not working anymore since switching to php7

Tags: apache2, phpmyadmin

The problem seems to be with this:

[phpmyadmin not working due to missing extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/755383/phpmyadmin-not-working-due-to-missing-extensions?newreg=ec085a7bf47c42c1931b4ca870dc2c4c)

But I have php-gettext installed, still it's not working. The log says this:

> [Fri Nov 11 00:22:06.899944 2016] [:error] [pid 19641] [client 93...:53244] PHP Warning:  require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/gettext.inc) is not within the allowed path(s): (/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/) in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 77
>   [Fri Nov 11 00:22:06.900007 2016] [:error] [pid 19641] [client 93...:53244] PHP Warning:  require_once(/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/gettext.inc): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 77
>   [Fri Nov 11 00:22:06.900027 2016] [:error] [pid 19641] [client 93...:53244] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php on line 77

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths Error is similar

Comment: No it is not. I was able to solve the issue by myself now. For whatever reason, the path is wrong and the directory is named php-php-gettext instead of php-gettext. I don't know whos fault it is, but this seems like a bug.

Comment: Nice.  You can answer your own question.  It's a great way to show how you worked it out for others who have similar issues :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after doing some updates.

I tried editing the vendor_config.php file but kept complaining, so I reverted the changes and went for the easy approach and just created a link to php-gettext with the expected name:

`cd /usr/share/php`

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/php/php-gettext php-php-gettext`

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

For some reason the path `/usr/share/php/php-gettext` is renamed (or wrong?) in the PHPMyAdmin files.

You have to change to files for this:

`/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/vendor_config.php`:

Change this block:

```
/**
 * Path to gettext.inc file. Useful when you want php-gettext somewhere else,
 * eg. /usr/share/php/gettext/gettext.inc.
 */
if (is_dir('/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/')) {
    define('GETTEXT_INC', '/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/gettext.inc');
} else {
    define('GETTEXT_INC', '/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/gettext.inc');
}
```

to this:

```
/**
 * Path to gettext.inc file. Useful when you want php-gettext somewhere else,
 * eg. /usr/share/php/gettext/gettext.inc.
 */
if (is_dir('/usr/share/php/php-gettext/')) {
    define('GETTEXT_INC', '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc');
} else {
    define('GETTEXT_INC', '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc');
}
```

And the configuration for the `open_basedir` in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf` to:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/phpseclib/
```

Alternatively (I didn't try it), you could copy or link the path `/usr/share/php/php-gettext/` to `/usr/share/php/php-php-gettext/`