# How to install php 7 to run beside php 5 on ubuntu with nginx

Tags: nginx, php7

I want to try php 7 and get my site working on php 7 in the same time keeping other sites working on php 5 just in case. so that from the domain virtual host config I can decide which php to run.

I looked at php version management and saw it is possible to run two versions, though the ones I found seems for apache.  I'm looking for more clear instructions on how to do this under nginx. I have also hhvm running in case that matters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, you need to install `php5-fpm` and `php7.0-fpm` from [Ondřej Surý's PPA for co-installable php5 and php7.0.](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php):

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

We then, with `nginx`, suggest using the FPM packages.  So, install the packages accordingly:

```
sudo apt-get update

# We need to ***remove*** php5 packages, so we can use php5.6 packages
# from the PPA instead
sudo apt-get remove php5-common
sudo apt-get autoremove

# Now we install php5.6 packages.
sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm

# Now, install php7.0-fpm.  You may need to install separate PHP plugins
# for databases, extensions, etc. later.
sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm
```

<sup>Source: [An answer on the "How to install php 7?" question](https://askubuntu.com/a/705893/10616), and custom comments and modifications from myself.</sup>

---

Secondly, `nginx`.  `nginx` is only able to be as good as your configurations.  You very likely have a PHP handling block on your nginx server block(s) similar to this (from the 'default' example config):

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

This configuration will only pass to `php5-fpm`.  In effect, this will apply for your entire server block.  The easiest way to go about this is to have a second server block (for, say, `test.domain.tld`), and provide instead the PHP 7.0 `fastcgi_pass` destination.  In php7.0 on Xenial, this is going to end up something like this (extracted from a fix recently uploaded to the Xenial nginx package), however I do not know the layout of Ondrej's package so I cannot give exact specifics there (check `/etc/php7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` or similar to determine where it's listening):

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php7.0-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

You will have to do something similar for your `php5` block, to validate that `php5.6` sockets are used instead of the built-in `php5` socket (which we just removed).

Then, use the second test domain to run the `php7.0` testing.  Make sure, though, to make a copy of your site if you want to do this - it will likely be necessary to have a separate testing copy so that once you've finished getting it working with `php7.0`, you can just 'switch over' without issue.

There is, unfortunately, no easy way to make `php5` and `php7.0` work within the same server block, not without altering your paths for your site, applications, etc. to have one for `php5` and one for `php7.0`; such reworking of sites can get nasty, hence the suggestion to run two separate copies of the site code, one for `php7.0` migration and one for `php5` in production.

Comment: If you pick this way, then you should stick to using the `*php5.6*` packages that Ondřej provides, and remove the plain `php5` packages.

Comment: @muru probably right, i'll write that in

Comment: Thanks!  This worked better than I expected.  there were problems with pear and cli at first, but turned out it was a bug in the repo I needed to update and it worked.  My site works really fast on php7. it's amazing.

Comment: The fpm sock had a 5.6 in the name as well.

Comment: As of almost 2018, the php5.6 config for NGINX is `fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;`