# Unable to install mbstring Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt

When I try to install `php7-mbstring` I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php7.0-mbstring : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3)
but 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried what is advice here: [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa). But it did'n work...
Any advice ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try `sudo apt install php7.0-common php7.0-mbstring`

Comment: Same problem...
I think my system is not getting the right version of mbstring.
But the package for 7.0.13 exists here : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/armhf/php7.0-mbstring/7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: How did you install `php 7`, do you remember ?

Comment: apt-get install php7.0-common

Comment: Did you do `sudo apt -f install` or you did `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: Yes I tried all of these already. Also removed and reinstall php7

Comment: Did you install php 7 with `sudo apt install php7.0` ?

Comment: what version of `php` are you using ?

Comment: I use php 7.0.13

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you installed PHP from an external/third-party repository. Note that the PHP repository has now been added to Ubuntu 16.04 so you need not add a repository in order to install it.  Try to uninstall and remove the PPA you added then install using: `sudo apt-get install php` . Hope that helps :) http://askubuntu.com/a/705893/476968

Comment: I finally managed to fix the problem.
My source.list did not have XENIAL PROPOSED enabled, and the mbstring package for php 7.0.13 was on this repo.
I added it to sources.list and then ran apt-get update && apt-get upgrade and it worked like a charm :)
Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to resolve the issue by searching for the package on Ubuntu depository.

The php7.0-mbstring for php 7.0.13 was on the proposed repository that wasn't in my source list

So I edited my sources.list in /etc/apt/sources.list by adding

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

then run `apt-get update` and then `apt-get install php7.0-mbstring`

Worked fine !